# Why is my NavigationLink grey, SwiftUI, Mac OS

Tags: swift, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-button

Why is my Cell Grey when I wrap it into a NavigationLink like that?

```
NavigationLink(
                destination: Einstellungen_Daten(),
                label: {
                    EinstellungenKachel(titel: "Daten", beschreibung: "In dieser Sektion der Einstellungen kannst du alles rund um deine Daten konfigurieren", bild: Image(systemName: "folder")).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

This Link looks like that:

[image: Greyed Link]

If I don't wrap *EinstellungenKachel* into a NavigationLink, it looks like this:

[image: Normal View]

The Code for *EinstellungenKachel* is like this:

```
struct EinstellungenKachel: View {
    
    var titel: String
    var beschreibung: String
    var bild: Image
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.gray
                .frame(width: 450, height: 450)
                .cornerRadius(45)
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
                .mask(bild.font(.system(size: 350)))
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                .foregroundColor(Color.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0))
                .overlay(textOverlay, alignment: .leading)
                .cornerRadius(45)
        }.frame(width: 450, height: 450)
        .padding()
    }
    
    var textOverlay: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(titel)
                .font(.custom("Impact", size: 50))
                .padding()
            Text(beschreibung)
                .font(.custom("Impact", size: 25))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Can please someone help me?
Thanks, Boothosh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `NavigationView`.

Consider this example which **doesn't** work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("NavigationLink", destination: Text("Destination"))
    }
}
```

Adding `NavigationView` around it, the `NavigationLink` will now be highlighted to indicate it is no longer disabled - since it can actually be tapped to navigate to some destination:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("NavigationLink", destination: Text("Destination"))
        }
    }
}
```

| Without `NavigationView` | With `NavigationView` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: without] | [image: with] |

Comment: Thank you, this does fixes the link colour but adds extra white view around my link, it also changes position of the NavigationLink with a button. This view is always white and I can't change its colour.

Comment: @BorisY. I assume it’s in a `List`? Might need a bit more detail to understand what you mean

Comment: No it's not in a `List`. I just want a Button which pushes another SwiftUI view. But I am not using a `List`.

Comment: @BorisY. I'm not sure what you mean, especially without images or code. Do you want to write a question and then put the link here?

Comment: change the button style to .borderless or .plain